# Is it possible to export an automation rule as a JSON file in Jira?

Tags: jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I would like to know if it is possible to export an automation rule as a JSON file and then import it in another instance of Jira, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some useful steps you can follow to achieve what you want.

**Exporting an automation rule:**

1. Go to the Automation section in Jira and select the rule you want to export.
2. Click on the three-dot menu in the top-right corner of the rule and select "Export" from the dropdown menu.
3. Save the exported JSON file to your computer.

**Importing an automation rule:**

1. Go to the Automation section in the Jira instance where you want to import the rule.
2. Click on the "Create rule" button and select "Import rule" from the dropdown menu.
3. Select the JSON file of the rule you want to import and click on "Import".
4. Review the imported rule and make any necessary adjustments before activating it.

Answer (score 0):

In jira, go to "gg" automation rules, navigate to the automation rule that you are interested in and choose the option "export"
[image]

This will export the checklist as a JSON file.